# Azure Data Explorer Table viewer

Tags: azure-data-explorer

We have a database in AzureDataExplorer. We want to provide read access to a principal only on selected tables. Right now, none of the roles mentioned in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/access-control/role-based-authorization) allow that. Is there a way to create a custom role or extend one of this roles to provide selective table access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point in time, there's no table-level read-only / viewer role, nor is there a way to define a custom role.

You could look into either of the following, and see if they can be made to work for your use case:

- Row level security policy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/rowlevelsecuritypolicy
- Restricted view access policy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/restrictedviewaccesspolicy